# flatten/un-stack excel pivot using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table

I have an excel pivot with data like:

```
Code      Region   Detail      Oct'17    Sep'17    Aug'17
AXISCGF   zone 1   IND3D01024  -82,000   0         900,000 
AXISDEF   zone 5   INP467B029   85,000   182,000   0
AXISEAF   zone 4   INZ514ELY4  -13,500   0         5,00,000 
AXISEQF   zone 2   INQ916D14E   0       -500,000   25,400
```

The output I would like to have is :

```
 Code      Region   Detail      Month    Change
 AXISCGF   zone 1   IND3D01024  Oct'17  -82,000   
 AXISDEF   zone 5   INP467B029  Oct'17   85,000
 ..
 AXISCGF   zone 1   IND3D01024  Sep'17   0
 AXISDEF   zone 5   INP467B029  Sep'17   182,000
```

I want the first three columns as it is and then append all the columns from 4th column onwards. I am able to loop through columns 4 to end. My code :

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('Data_2017.xlsx', sheet_name='Sales')

for data_column in df.columns[3:10]:
    df_new = df.filter(['Code','Region','Detail',data_column])
    #print df_new.head()
    df_new.to_csv('_TEST_Output.csv',mode='a')
```

The output :

```
     Code      Region   Detail      Oct'17    
 0   AXISCGF   zone 1   IND3D01024  -82,000   
 1   AXISDEF   zone 5   INP467B029   85,000   
..
3501 AXISESF   zone 3   INO0201062   0
     Code      Region   Detail      Sep'17    
 0   AXISDEF   zone 5   INP467B029  182,000
```

How can I get the desired output using pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = df.melt(['Code','Region','Detail'], value_name='Change', var_name='Month')
print (df)
       Code  Region      Detail   Month    Change
0   AXISCGF  zone 1  IND3D01024  Oct'17   -82,000
1   AXISDEF  zone 5  INP467B029  Oct'17    85,000
2   AXISEAF  zone 4  INZ514ELY4  Oct'17   -13,500
3   AXISEQF  zone 2  INQ916D14E  Oct'17         0
4   AXISCGF  zone 1  IND3D01024  Sep'17         0
5   AXISDEF  zone 5  INP467B029  Sep'17   182,000
6   AXISEAF  zone 4  INZ514ELY4  Sep'17         0
7   AXISEQF  zone 2  INQ916D14E  Sep'17  -500,000
8   AXISCGF  zone 1  IND3D01024  Aug'17   900,000
9   AXISDEF  zone 5  INP467B029  Aug'17         0
10  AXISEAF  zone 4  INZ514ELY4  Aug'17  5,00,000
11  AXISEQF  zone 2  INQ916D14E  Aug'17    25,400
```

Another solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), but there is different ordering of values in columns:

```
df = (df.set_index(['Code','Region','Detail'])
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name='Change')
       .rename(columns={'level_3':'Month'}))

print (df)
       Code  Region      Detail   Month    Change
0   AXISCGF  zone 1  IND3D01024  Oct'17   -82,000
1   AXISCGF  zone 1  IND3D01024  Sep'17         0
2   AXISCGF  zone 1  IND3D01024  Aug'17   900,000
3   AXISDEF  zone 5  INP467B029  Oct'17    85,000
4   AXISDEF  zone 5  INP467B029  Sep'17   182,000
5   AXISDEF  zone 5  INP467B029  Aug'17         0
6   AXISEAF  zone 4  INZ514ELY4  Oct'17   -13,500
7   AXISEAF  zone 4  INZ514ELY4  Sep'17         0
8   AXISEAF  zone 4  INZ514ELY4  Aug'17  5,00,000
9   AXISEQF  zone 2  INQ916D14E  Oct'17         0
10  AXISEQF  zone 2  INQ916D14E  Sep'17  -500,000
11  AXISEQF  zone 2  INQ916D14E  Aug'17    25,400
```

Comment: super thanks. have been struggling for quite some time now. both the solutions work really well. thanks once again.

Comment: You are welcome! And if possible, you can upvote too. Thanks.